# VueJS Bubble Component Events

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to make a Vue component (of a custom canvas element) but have found that the component's regular events don't seem to bubble to the parent. Is there something obvious I'm doing wrong?

I really don't want to have to emit every possible HTML event from the component if I can avoid it. And if it's not clear: I am NOT talking about custom events - just onmousemove etc..

TIA

```
<div id="app">
  <xon-canvas @mousemove="handleMove"></xon-canvas>
</div>
```

---

```
Vue.component('XonCanvas', {
  template: '<canvas width="500" height="500"></canvas>'
  })

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    handleMove (event) { console.log("I worked!") }
  }
});
```

[CodePe Code](https://codepen.io/xon5/pen/pKevRE?editors=1010)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One quick fix is adding v-on="$listeners"

```
Vue.component('XonCanvas', {
  template: '<canvas v-on="$listeners" width="500" height="500"></canvas>'
  }
)
```

https://codepen.io/ittus/pen/mKWyxZ

Comment: Wow, didn't even know about that one. For anyone else following here's the docs:
https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-listeners